# How to makebox plots in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, boxplot, spss

How to make boxplot in ubuntu.

I have .csv format file.

I made it on LibreOffice. But it took a long time.

I need thorugh simplest way/software like SPSS.

Can I install SPSS on ubuntu 14.04?

I am beginner.Please guide me

Comment: please specify which programming language are you using and what did you try so far

Comment: I got 'CPU usage and GPU usage data' log files with the help of top command.
files are in csv format.
I wanted to compare and plot data using boxplot.

Comment: These are just number (values in perfcentage).
I already access the data using this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSb-iKq0L5s

but it is quite hactic to do with each variable.. and also 1 want to make more then 1 boxplots at a time.

Comment: ask this question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ since you need a software and you are not looking for a programming based solution.

Comment: oh Thank you for guiding me the right path. :)